# Access parent Iframe from polymer element

Tags: iframe, polymer

I have an element that loads in an iframe that is contained in another element, something like this:

```
<polymer-element>

<iframe>
  <html>
    <body>
      <polymer-element>
      </polymer-element>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>

<polymer-element>
```

I need to access from the element inside to the outside of the iframe, I was trying with this.parentNode, but only reach the html tag. I tried also with core-signals but neither worked.

Comment: maybe use window.top?

Comment: yes, finally window.parent works, the easy way is always the best option.